# How do I change mode in cases LaTeX

Tags: latex, equation

When I write a `\prod` in a `cases`, the `\prod` is like if it was in inline mode.

```latex
\mathbb{P} : \left\{ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Big| \nexists d \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1; n\} : d|n \right\}\\

\mathbb{P}_n \subset \mathbb{P} \times \mathbb{N}^* :
\begin{cases}
\left( \prod_{(k, m) \in \mathbb{P}_n} k^m \right ) = n\\
\forall (k; m) \in \mathbb{P}_n, \nexists (k'; m') \in \mathbb{P}_n \setminus \{(k, m)\}:k=k'
\end{cases}\\
```

[image: LaTeX example]

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it is in [the amsmath manual](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) after all (page 9):

> `cases` is set in `\textstyle`. If `\displaystyle` is wanted, it must be requested explicitly; `mathtools` provides a `dcases` environment for this purpose.

See the [mathtools manual](https://mirror.lyrahosting.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf):

> Using the `dcases` environment you get the same output as with `cases` except that the rows are set in display style.

So this should work (untested though):

```
\usepackage{mathtools}

...

\begin{dcases}
\left( \prod_{(k, m) \in \mathbb{P}_n} k^m \right ) = n\\
\forall (k; m) \in \mathbb{P}_n, \nexists (k'; m') \in \mathbb{P}_n \setminus \{(k, m)\}:k=k'
\end{dcases}
```

Comment: I can't use mathtools, I know, it's problematic...

Comment: Then you might be able to switch to display style explicitly using `{\displaystyle ...}`. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63737/using-displaystyle-in-equation-environment#63738).

Comment: I just found this (just before seeing your message), thanks for your help, have a nice day!